# openssl sha256 binary digest piped through fxxd -p is output on multiple lines

Tags: bash, multiline

I use this command to give me the output from openssl without the (stdin)= the beginning.

```
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in certfile.crt | openssl sha1 -binary | xxd -p
```

with output

```
7857b35259019acc7484201958ac7e622c227b68
```

If I change openssl to create a sha256 digest, xxd prints it over two lines

```
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in certfile.crt | openssl sha256 -binary | xxd -p
```

with output

```
b274c19ac31cc7893dc2297804a2ca666fe168d5cd5eb4d4b6c47616bad9
8996
```

How can I write that output on line one?

```
b274c19ac31cc7893dc2297804a2ca666fe168d5cd5eb4d4b6c47616bad98996
```

Is it something else I have to do with xxd now that the digest is longer or is there a need to pipe it through some other command to get the combined output?

Comment: How about adding `-c 256` option to `xxd` as `xxd -p -c 256`?

Comment: If you are looking to just get the two lined output on one line, you can pipe through xargs and printf and so openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in certfile.crt | openssl sha256 -binary | xxd -p | xargs printf "%s"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual there are several ways.
The first general solution which came into my mind is this:

```
printf "%s" $( openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in certfile.crt | openssl sha256 -binary | xxd -p )
```

Of course, if the output is less than 256, you could use `xxd -p -c 256` as stated by tshiono.

Another solution for this special case with `openssl` would be this:

```
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in certfile.crt | openssl sha256 -r
```

or

```
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in certfile.crt | openssl sha256 -hex
```

but both are not exactly like the output you want. The hex string is in the output, but padded before or after which can be `cut` off, by piping to the command `cut -d" " -f 1` or `cut -d" " -f 2` for the removal of the prefix or postfix.

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks for all the options you gave me.

Comment: This answer was exactly what I was looking for. Was seeing two lines in the xxd output, but adding `-c 256` put it on one line. Thanks!